# Need correct regular expression to get MAC-Address and Port number

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a python script to retrieve Port-number and associated MAC-Address of a network switch from a browser based software I am using to monitor network.

Below is the part of source code I've to pass through regular expression-

```
            <td Class="Property"><input id =  "1933"type = "checkbox" onclick="javascript:SaveSelectedNodes();" /></td>
            <td Class="Property"><img src="/Orion/UDT/Images/Status/icon_port_active_dot.gif" title="Active port" alt="active port" style="vertical-align:bottom;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/NetPerfMon/images/Interfaces/6.gif" title="ethernet-csmacd" alt="ethernet-csmacd" style="vertical-align:bottom;" />&nbsp;</td>
            <td Class="Property"><a href=/Orion/UDT/PortDetails.aspx?NetObject=UP:1933 @tooltip=""">Fa0/18</a></td>
            <td Class="Property" Style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td Class="Property" Style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td Class="Property" Style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px"><div id='VendorIconDiv' border='0' class='VendorIconcss' style='vertical-align:middle; background:url(../../../../NetPerfMon/images/Vendors/1602.gif) no-repeat; padding-left:20px; height:16px; line-height:16px; font-size: 8pt !important;'></div></td>
            <td Class="Property" Style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px"><a href='/Orion/UDT/EndpointDetails.aspx?NetObject=UE-MAC:VAL=F4:81:39:BA:07:91';>F4:81:39:BA:07:91</a></td>
            <td Class="Property" Style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px">213</td>
            <td Class="Property" Style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td Class="Property" Style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px"><a href='/Orion/UDT/EndpointDetails.aspx?NetObject=UE-MAC:VAL=B4:A2:c1:BA:81:32';>B4:A2:c1:BA:81:32</a></td>
            <td Class="Property" Style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px">213</td>
            <td Class="Property" Style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px">&nbsp;</td>
```

So, I need to get 3 values from this source-

1-   Fa0/18
2-   MAC Address- F4:81:39:BA:07:91
3-   MAC Address- B4:A2:c1:BA:81:32

I have the regular-expression for all these two different values-

`r'.+@tooltip=""">(.+)</a>'` - for the value Fa0/18
`r'.+MAC:VAL.+(\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w).+'`  - for the mac address

But I could not develop a Regex for getting all of them together. I need to collect them at a time in somewhat below format-

```
Fa0/18
F4:81:39:BA:07:91
B4:A2:c1:BA:81:32

Fa0/19
<mac address-1>

FA0/20
<mac address-1>
<mac address-2>
```

The source of the page contains lots of entries as I gave in a sample code. There can be multiple MAC Addresses for one Port. So will have to collect those addresses also after the port collection.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​You're trying to parsing some HTML data, why not use an HTML parser like **BeautifulSoup** instead of RegEx?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough source code to know where is it safe to split the text. But assuming 'tooltip' is unique enough, that should do the job:

```
import re 

def findall_macs(source):
    fragments = source.split('tooltip')
    for frag in fragments: 
        title = ""
        if re.findall('=""">(.+?)<', frag):
            title = re.findall('=""">(.+?)<', frag)[0]
        macs = set(re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}', frag))
        print title 
        print "\n".join(macs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    findall_macs(source)
```